# Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: eclipse, apache, struts2

The error "Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.NullPointerException" is shown when i Try to run my application. I am programming in Eclipse 3.6 on Struts 2. part of my My Struts.xml looks like below:

```
   <struts>
    <!-- remove these constant elements in production -->
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="app02a" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="Product_input">
            <result>/jsp/Product.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="Product_save" class="app02a.Product" method="execute">
            <result>/jsp/Details.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

Comment: I found the solution, it was simple.Make struts.devMode from 'true' to 'false' in the line shown below. Its inside the struts.xml

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />


The struts.devMode stands for the development mode

Comment: That just makes the reporting of the exception go away--might you want to know what's causing the exception and why? You shouldn't be getting an NPE on startup.

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out. I was under the impression that it was neglegible. Actually, I got the solution from the [stuts issues link] (http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/2-0-14-2-1-6-filter-config-issue-tp3490585p3490586.html) . I have been trying out tutorials from the book 'Struts 2 Design and Programming a Tutorial (2008)'. Perhaps the codes are too old? Could you figure out something else form this scenario?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Apart form changing dev mode to false, what was the solution you got? Can you please share it with me, it will be really helpful for me